# Nodejs app hangs when there is no interval running

Tags: node.js, request, setinterval, electron

So I have been building a cli/gui app using electron for work. I have a progress bar that needs an interval to be run every so often to refresh the progress bar. Recently we wanted to run this in jenkins so having progress bars refresh ever 80 ms would be super anoying. I added some code to clear the interval if a certain environment variable was set and then for some reason the app started to hang after sending http requests. The server would never receive the requests and the app would just sit there.  After a lot of debugging i have found that putting a `setInterval(() => { }, 80);` (one that does anything or nothing for any amount of time) anywhere in the code fixes the problem. Has anyone seen this before? i feel like I'm going crazy!

**edit:**
setting a timeout on the request will make the request fail after the timeout.

**edit:**

so I can't show you the exact code but here is the jist of one of the request calls.

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      request.put({
        url: this.buildUrl(armada, '/some-path'),
        body: vars,
        json: true
      }, (err, resp, body) => {
        logger.comment('err "%s"', JSON.stringify(err));
        logger.comment('resp "%s"', JSON.stringify(resp));
        logger.comment('body "%s"', JSON.stringify(body));
        let e = this.handleError(err, resp, body, 'Error getting stuff');
        if (e) { return reject(e); }
        logger.comment('got back body "%s"', body);
        resolve(resp);
      });
    });
```

and then if I have an interval somewhere it doesn't hang. and if I don't it does.

i can paste this code anywhere in my code and everything starts working

```
setInterval(() => { }, 80);
```

Now it's not a specific request made as the app makes a lot of different requests. any of the requests it makes can hang. And they don't always hang. about 1 in 10 times everything will work just fine for an individual request.

Comment: I think we're going to need more information about what the rest of your code is doing because adding a `setInterval()` shouldn't have any effect on a web server waiting for incoming requests.  Are you sure the app is still running when you say it's hung?  Could it have thrown some sort of exception and exited?  What do you see in the console?

Comment: so it is still running because the timeout on the request works. Also this app is sending requests not receiving them. It seems as though the request is never being sent when the interval doesn't exist.

Comment: Show us the relevant code

Comment: Why is this in there: `"${JSON.stringify(vars)}"`);`?

Comment: bad copy/paste. fixed.